# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'id' available as request attribute

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I keep getting the "Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'id' available as request attribute" error when try to add the related user iterating through the loop.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model,  @RequestParam("id") String id, @ModelAttribute("userForm") UserForm userForm)
{
    User user = userService.getUser(id);
    List<User> relateUsers = userService.getRelatedUsers(id);
    userForm.setUser(user);
    userForm.setRelateUsers(relateUsers);
    return userDetailForm;

}



<div class="trackList" th:if="${userForm.relatedUsers.size() > 0}" th:each="relatedUser : ${userForm.relatedUsers}"  >

<th:form method="POST" th:action="@{/user}">                              
              <input type="hidden" id="id" th:field="*{id}"/>
                <div>
              <a class="add"  role="button">Add</a>
                        </div>
</th:form>


</div>
```

Comment: i think you did mistake <a class="add"  role="button">Add</a> you can put submit button instead of link may be its work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helped me to bind value to model attribute, using this code :

```
<input type="hidden" th:id="id" th:name="id" th:value="*{id}"/>
```

Comment: <input type="hidden" th:id="id" th:name="id" th:value="*{id}"/>

It helped me to bind value to model attribute

Answer (score 1):

Your example is weird because your handler just maps to a `GET` request. Anyway, your method signature of your `POST` handler is invalid in respect to `BindingResult`.

[Spring Framework documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-methods) says:

> org.springframework.validation.Errors / org.springframework.validation.BindingResult validation results for a preceding command or form object (the immediately preceding method argument).

You have to change method signature of your POST handler from something like that

```
@Valid @ModelAttribute("userForm") UserForm userForm, @RequestParam("id") String id
```

to

```
@Valid @ModelAttribute("userForm") UserForm userForm, BindingResult result, @RequestParam("id") String id
```